# .NET Multiple Data Filters

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've been using the EF6 tutorial and created filters which work great! However the guide only shows how to make one filter. I've made multiple filters, though they need different strings to operate. However pagination uses searchString (one of the filter strings) to display based on filtered results. How can I operate multiple filters alongside pagination??

Filters and pagination:

```
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var clients = from s in db.Clients.Include(c => c.MJTopics).Include(c => c.UserTable)
        select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(s => s.clientN.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.homePage.Contains(searchString));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NameString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(s => s.clientEmail.Contains(NameString)
                                   || s.contName.Contains(NameString));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RIString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(s => s.clientN.Contains(RIString));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TopicString))
        {
            clients = clients.Where(s => s.MJTopics.topicalTF.Contains(TopicString));
        }
```

Pagination view:

```
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
             new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

Filters in view:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p class="filtertext">Filter Clients:</p>
            <p class="filterbox">@Html.TextBox("searchString")</p>
            <p class="filterbox2"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default btn-sm selector2" /> </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p class="filtertext">Find by Name: </p>
            <p class="filterbox"> @Html.TextBox("NameString")</p>
            <p class="filterbox2"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default btn-sm selector2" /></p>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Pagination is actually a simple `.Skip(pages*pageSize).Take(pageSize)`. It shouldn't need any strings. PagedListPager isn't a built-in helper. Which package did you use? [This one](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) for example works with LINQ just fine.

Comment: How about *not* providing a filter since your own code defines the query?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application used this, PagedList.mvc

Comment: that's a tutorial. You used *PagedList.Mvc* which was abandoned back in 2013. The site says `IMPORTANT: This package is no longer maintained` and points to https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PagedList.Mvc](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) project was abandoned in 2013. The site warns:

> IMPORTANT: This package is no longer maintained. Please see ernado-x/X.PagedList for a drop-in replacement.

Although 5 years later, the changes may be big enough that you can't just replace one with the other.

The Nuget package for the replacement is [X.PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc)

The examples on the [Github repo](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) show that it uses IQueryable< T> directly, without filter strings, eg :

```
var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
return View();
```

and

```
<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Comment: Ahh I see! I installed it straight through nugget so I didn't see it had been abandoned. I shall look at implementing this! thank you :)